# Finding Unique Words In A Text File Using ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a project where I enter a URL, the file is read and the amount of lines, characters, and words are outputted in a text file. I'm not having an issue with that. Code below will be pretty long, sorry in advance.

I also have to output to the same text file all of the words in the file, and the amount of times each word is displayed in the file. I've been working on it for a while and I've gotten to the point where all the lines/characters/words are outputted to the text file, but I can't figure out how to display the actual words and the amount of times they are in the file.

```
                String[] wordSubstrings = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").split(" ");

                List<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < wordSubstrings.length; i++) {
                    if (!(uniqueWords.contains(wordSubstrings[i]))) {
                        uniqueWords.add(wordSubstrings[i]);
```

Comment: You can use hashmap instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, the file that I'm inputting in is https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt

And the output is:

# of lines in file 116
# of words in file 753
# of characters in file 3775

Comment: Don't use `x.replace(regex,str).split(str)` because `x.split(regex)` achieves the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arraylist of class which will contain word and count as member variables.

```
List <MyClass> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<MyClass> ();

MyClass()
{
 String uniqueword;
 int count;
}
```

Comment: Multiset (see Vixen's A) or a HashMap are preferred; using lists is getting slower with an increasing number of different words. But it seems that OP has been instructed not to use that.

Comment: Yep, wish I could. Sadly it's a project and that's why I'm kind of lost. I don't understand how using a getter or compareTo method will get the words from the List.

Comment: @laune I know using list will slower down the performance but considering John's reuirement as he is willing to use only list I have suggested so.

Comment: To search if a word is already there in the list, you can use list.contains() this will return true or false accordingly.

Comment: @John You can use the idea of this answer. A compareTo should compare two objects, based on the `uniqueword` only. Then, add a method `count`, to increment the counter, a toString, and the obvious constructor.

Comment: Did you find any othe answers useful?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Multiset](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html)

```
Multiset<String> words = HashMultiset.create();
for (String word : wordList)
    words.add(word);

for (String word : words.elementSet())
    System.out.println(word + ": " + words.count(word));
```

Comment: Not allowed to use a multiSet :(

I'm supposed to use a getter method or compareTo to extract the words from the ArrayList, although I don't understand how that makes sense.

Comment: @John Right: it does not "make sense". Using poor techniques to solve a problem isn't something one should have to learn. Using a list isn't good; if you must, you should use List.contains rather than roll your own by iterating and comparing List entries one by one.  - Change the school, if you can ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested something with a HashMap which seems to work pretty well.

Here is my code that I used to test it, I hope it helps:

```
String[] wordSubstrings = new String[]{"test","stuff","test","thing","test","test","stuff"};
HashMap<String,Integer> uniqueWords = new HashMap<>();

for ( int i = 0; i < wordSubstrings.length; i++)
{
    if(!(uniqueWords.containsKey(wordSubstrings[i])))
    {
        uniqueWords.put(wordSubstrings[i], 1);
    }
    else
    {
        int number = uniqueWords.get(wordSubstrings[i]);
        uniqueWords.put(wordSubstrings[i],number + 1);
    }
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : uniqueWords.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    int value = entry.getValue();

     //Do Something with the key and value
}
```